# How to open a text file in SSH virtual machine in Google cloud platform?

Tags: ssh, cmd, google-cloud-platform

How can I open a text file in google cloud platform? The script says I have to agree to a text file called EULA, open the text file on a text editor and change the last form eula=false to eula=true. How can I accomplish this?

```
a_castro4@mc-server:/home/minecraft$ sudo java -Xms1G -Xmx7G -d64 -jar 
minecraft_server.1.11.2.jar nogui
[01:05:30] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting minecraft server version 1.11.2
[01:05:30] [Server thread/INFO]: Loading properties
[01:05:30] [Server thread/INFO]: You need to agree to the EULA in order to 
run the server. Go to eula.txt for more 
info.
[01:05:30] [Server thread/INFO]: Stopping server
a_castro4@mc-server:/home/minecraft$
```

One file is the server.properties which you could edit to change the default behavior of the minecraft server.
Use your favorite text editor to edit the eula.txt file. Remember to use sudo so you can save the edit. Change the last line that says eula=false to eula=true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily create and edit files using the `nano` or `vim` tools. If you are new to this environment, I would suggest you to go with `nano`, which should be easier to understand for beginners.

A set of simple steps to edit the file you want is:

1. Go to the directory where your file is located.
2. Write the command `sudo nano eula.txt` in the terminal; `sudo` will ensure that you have permissions for editing the file.
3. Move to the end of the file with your arrow keys and write the change in your file.
4. Press `Ctrl + X` to exit the application, then `Y` to save changes.

Your file should be edited right now.